# manually create a plot frame in R

Tags: r, plot, frame

I need to control the style of a basic xy plot in R, and so have build the plotting area like this:

```
frame()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-.6, .8))
axis(1, at=c(0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0), lwd=2)
axis(2, at=c(-.6, -.4, -.2, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8), lwd=2)
```

I cannot, however, figure out how to create a physical frame around this plot (with lwd = 2). Is it possible (necessary?) to use `line()` or `polygon()`? Or is there something more built-in for this?

I'm also interested in how to change the frame and axis weights for a plot created using the `plot()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean `box()`:

```
frame()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-.6, .8))
axis(1, at=c(0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0), lwd=2)
axis(2, at=c(-.6, -.4, -.2, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8), lwd=2)
box(lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! why is this so hard to find out there?